# Numerical solution for gradient(slope)

Tags: numerics

**Abstract**

I have the next equation to find a force, for my problem:

$$U=-\int \vec{m}\small{(x)}\times \vec{B}(x)dV$$
$$\vec{F}=-\nabla U$$

Considering 3-dimensional space with x,y,z coordinates, and, hence, $\vec{m}$ and $\vec{B}$ describe values at a point in the 3D space. Computing via C++. Each values described as:

```
class Vector3
{
public:
float x;
float y;
float z;
Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
{
   this->x=x;
   this->y=y;
   this->z=z;
}
};

Vector3 *m[1000];
Vector3 *B[1000];
Vector3 *F[1000];
```

Using: finding F vector literally at every point is impossible, so I will find values with some step. For example, considering some volume 1m*1m*1m, I will find values with step 100mm, so for that volume I need to calculate $\frac{1m}{100mm}* \frac{1m}{100mm}* \frac{1m}{100mm} =10^3=1000\space points$.

Fill array, I think should be the next way:

```
 int count=0;
 for(float x=0.0f;x<1.0f;x+=0.1f)
  for(float y=0.0f;y<1.0f;y+=0.1f) 
   for(float Z=0.0f;z<1.0f;z+=0.1f, count++)
      F[count]=new Vector3(...)\\here I calculate the formulas above
```

And I have particles, that move more smoothly, of course, not by 100mm steps, so I will just calculate which point is the nearest, or the average value of the nearest points in that point.

**Question**

How should I deal with it, if I have literally an array of $\vec{m}$ and $\vec{B}$ at every point, but not an analytical function, that describes distribution of that values?

As the output I need also array with $\vec{F}$ at every point.

**Thoughts**

I am bad at math, and have, probably wrong assumption. The formulas above wrote for finding **field** of forces. But in my case in need it to be “dotty”. Here is potential energy at a point.

$$\vec{m}\small{(x)}\times \vec{B}(x) = \frac{J}{T}*T=Joules=Potential\space Energy $$

But it doesn’t have any sense, because I need the **difference between two potentials**. So what if to calculate $\vec{F}(x)$(at a point) as 
$$\vec{F}(x)=\frac{U(x+k)-U(x)}{k}$$
Taking $k=step=100mm$?

Comment: I don't understand what the integral in the first equation extends over. From the $dV$, I presume that it is a volume integral, in which case $U$ is just a number. But then using $\nabla U$ makes no sense in the second equation because $U$ is just a number, not a function that depends on space...

Comment: I think each cell has its own U maybe?

Comment: @EMP yes, correct

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, someone gave me that formulas. I will ask have I rewrote it correctly

Comment: @АртурКлочко But if that is a cellwise quantity, then $\nabla U$ still doesn't make sense for two reasons: First, it is a piecewise constant quantity. So the gradient is either zero or infinite (a distribution); the best one could hope for is a numerical approximation. But second, and more importantly, if it is a cellwise quantity then it is proportional to the volume of the cell. As a consequence, it converges to zero under mesh refinement. It doesn't converge to any physical quantity. For that, you would have to normalize it by the cells' volumes.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, I’m sorry I forgot about that, I have already solved this issue, in another stack site, I will put answer here later. Here is the question (answer is in the bottom of the question) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/554122/260037

Comment: There is another problem $F$ does not seem to be a vector since it's the gradient of a vector.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question needs more details, but couldn't you just use gauss-divergence theorem to move the gradient inside the integral and transform the volume integral to a surface integral. Maybe you can use a least squares approach to get the gradient in each cell?

Comment: >More details, which exactly? I will add, no problem

Comment: 1)What is the purpose to use Gauss-divergence theorem? Just for simplification? 2) *Least squares to get the gradient*, can You give more details or, provide an example?

Comment: Also as for Gauss theorem, I have gradient, not a divergence operation

Comment: One approach could be to construct an analytic function matching your data points. Is the domain 2D or 3D? Any symmetries? Is data given on a regular grid? How large are grid dimensions?

Comment: @MaximUmansky, wow, I actually  thought about getting the analytical equation from points as the last solution to apply. I thought it’s kinda trivial task. 1) What do You mean by symmetries?

Comment: There are different approaches for constructing an analytic function matching existing data points, and the choice may depend on things like whether the function is supposed to be periodic in a certain dimension, or supposed to have zero gradient at a certain plane etc. It is basically interpolation, and it may not be necessary for the interpolating function to go through every single data point. Depends on the dimensionality, the size of data set, whether the data points are exact, or they have error bars. With more information of that kind one can perhaps propose a specific approach to try.